# Order ListView animation

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-listview, android-animation

I have a listView (listFragment actually) with a lot of items. When I click on a item I want it to rise to the top of the list. I guess this in itself is pretty straight forward, but is it possible to attach some kind of transition annimation in order to not just make it appear at the top.

Also, I want the list to scroll to the top when an item is clicked so the item continues to be visible.

Hope you can provide some insight in how to do this

Comment: If you want the list to also scroll when the item is going to the top, can't you simply manually scroll the list so the clicked item becomes the first visible position?

Comment: @Luksprog Sure, but that was more a bonus information. The main problem is how to animate the reordering when the list doesn't scroll

Comment: Just to be clear, when clicked, do you want the row to get to top(the first visible position) of the current part of the `ListView` or do you want it to move to the 0 position of the `ListView` with also scrolling the list?

Comment: All the way to the top. if my list contains A-Z and currently I-M is visible on the screen. Then (when clicked on) M should move up and be placed before A. But as I said, this is pretty easy. The hard part is if I'm looking at A-E and clock C - now there is no scrolling